# How to splash gif on the same activity for few seconds

Tags: android, android-layout

On game over, I want to show a GIF image in the same activity with background faded out.

I tried creating a new splash screen with a GIFImageView .And in my "gameover" method starting the activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

but, this is not what I want. A new activity with white background is created on "gameover" method. How do I display the GIF in the same activity with faded background?

This is my SplashActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="559dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fireworks"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the java code for the activity is here:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 8000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

But, is has become separate activity. I wanted to make my gif as part of the same main activity. Just make it visible when "gameover" method is called.

Comment: I think ObjectAnimator can work for your requirement. Please see this if it may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSgUn2rZiko

Comment: plz paste SplashActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, by moving the gif image view to main activity

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/fireworks_gif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:src="@drawable/fireworks"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

And then after the "gameover" method

```
GifImageView fireworks = findViewById(R.id.fireworks_gif);
            fireworks.setVisibility(GifImageView.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /* Create an Intent that will start the Main-Activity. */
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                    this.finish();
                }
            }, 10000);
```

Hence, the gif view is there for 10s and then automatically redirected to MainActivity.